# How to reversing a number without forming palindrome

Tags: java

I am try to solve a challenge. This is what I have been able to do, but I haven't been able to get  100%  working code

Am I doing something wrong?

Question:

> The problem is as follows: choose a number, reverse its digits and add
>   it to the original. If the sum is not a palindrome (which means, it is
>   not the same number from left to right and right to left), repeat this
>   procedure.

```
import java.io.*;
    public class Reverse_and_add {

        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
            File file = new File("addition.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                String[] addition = line.split(" ");
                int[] myAddition = new int[addition.length];
                int convert = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < myAddition.length; i++) {
                    myAddition[i] = Integer.parseInt(addition[i]);
                    convert = myAddition[i];
                }
               int  result=0;
               int count =0;
               result = convert + reverse(convert);
                   do {
                     result = result + reverse(result);
                     System.out.println(count+" "+result);
                     count++;
                   } while (result != reverse(result));


            }
        }

        public static int reverse(int n){
            int reverse = 0;
            while( n != 0 )
              {
                  reverse = reverse * 10;
                  reverse = reverse + n%10;
                  n = n/10;
              }
            return reverse;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete this problem, you have to break it down.  There are three parts, reversing it, checking if it is a palindrome, and adding until completion.  I pretty much broke down the problem and then implemented it in the following code.  Please do note: the implementation for the methods `isPalindrome()` and `reverseInt()` were taken from other SO threads.   **However you implement getting the value for the problem is up to you.**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int num = 54; //THis can be whatever you want
        while(!isPalindrome(Integer.toString(num))){
            int n = reverseInt(num);
            num +=n;
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    //Checks if a number is a string is a palindrome
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }

    //Takes an int, reverses it
    public static int reverseInt(int input)
    {
        long reversedNum = 0;

        long input_long = input;

        while (input_long != 0)
        {
            reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + input_long % 10;
            input_long = input_long / 10;
        }

        if (reversedNum > Integer.MAX_VALUE || reversedNum < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return (int)reversedNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...Let me break it down into three parts and try it again. You code simplifies the problem. I get the idea now. I will try and use a similar approach. @intboolstring

Comment: @Dragonstone.  If this helped you, could you accept it?

Comment: Thanks @intboolstring

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is right here:

```
result = convert + reverse(convert);
    do {
        result = result + reverse(result);
        //
    }
```

It will reverse the number and add it twice in a row, with no check in between. For example if your number is 7, the line just before the `do..while` will make result equal to 14, and the first line in the `do..while` will make it equal to 55. This is unintended as 14 is obviously not a palindrome, which means the program should stop, but instead it is skipped entirely.

Comment: True. I tried a lot of solutions this was the only solution that worked. Didn't notice it created the silence bug.@Shadow

Comment: @Dragonstone The other answer is over-complicated. All you need to do is fix these 3 lines, easily done changing the `do..while` to a regular `while`, and you won't have any other problems

Comment: @Shadow: I would disagree that my answer is overcomplicated.  Pretty much, I abstracted every part of the problem.  I took the problem and broke it down into parts.  Those 20-30 lines of code should not be scary.

Comment: @intboolstring you have 2 separate reverse methods when only the 1 is needed, as OP has in his question. It was unnecessary to write 2 separate ones, one the same as OP's but more complicated